# Angular Material drag n drop after change order first element removed

Tags: angular, angular-material

I try Drag&Drop sorting same example asi it is on material webpage [Example](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/examples#cdk-drag-drop-sorting). It works but when I change order (move one item to another position) first element in this list disappear. I have one
cdkDropList and change just order of items. I do not know why every time when I move anny item first item is removed. I use the same code as it is on material webpage example.

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  @for (movie of movies; track movie) {
    <div class="example-box" cdkDrag>{{movie}}</div>
  }
</div>



import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CdkDragDrop, CdkDropList, CdkDrag, moveItemInArray} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

/**
 * @title Drag&Drop sorting
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example',
  templateUrl: 'cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CdkDropList, CdkDrag],
})
export class CdkDragDropSortingExample {
  movies = [
    'Episode I - The Phantom Menace',
    'Episode II - Attack of the Clones',
    'Episode III - Revenge of the Sith',
    'Episode IV - A New Hope',
    'Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back',
    'Episode VI - Return of the Jedi',
    'Episode VII - The Force Awakens',
    'Episode VIII - The Last Jedi',
    'Episode IX – The Rise of Skywalker',
  ];

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.movies, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gsudtm?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Share a reproducible example, elsewhise you might not get any help with this.

Comment: As i write I use the same code as it is in example on Angular Material page. On their page it works, when i run it on my localhost it remove first item.

Comment: Try to reconstruct your problem on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/), it's probably the best solution for Angular apps

Comment: I add stackblitz link but there it works fine, problem is only on my computer

Comment: @Marko, if works in stackblitz, check the version of your Angular, and your  @angular/cdk. You can see them in your package.json

Comment: @Eliseo version is the same

Comment: try use **$index** as track:`@for (movie of movies; track $index)`. NOTE: Really the function moveItemInArray, can be translate like:`const movie=this.movies[event.previousIndex];this.movies.splice(event.previousIndex,1);this.movies.splice(event.currentIndex,0,movie)` or use the code in [github](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/cdk/drag-drop/drag-utils.ts)

Comment: @Eliseo $index helps. It works now. thank you.